# Git branches are not separate

Tags: git, visual-studio

We are using Visual Studio  2017 with GIT.  I just made a "New Local Branch From" my coworkers branch.  Every change I made is immediately made in his branch.  I have googled and cannot figure out why.  Every time one of us makes a change,  the other gets a popup "The file has been changed externally...".

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you working on some kind of shared file system?

Comment: We have git on the server, is that what you mean.

Comment: No, I'm asking if the source files you're compiling are on a shared server. Normally each of you would have your working files on your own system. If updating a file on your system (without regard to Git) updates the file on your coworker's system, then you're both seeing the same file. The "The had been changed externally" message, if I understand it correctly, isn't about Git; it's about your working copy.

Comment: I am actually just helping a co-worker with his project. Turns out that his code is on the server.  Mine is on my machine. However, since we are in different branches wouldn't why would it matter?

Comment: If your coworker is getting "The file has been changed externally" messages, it means that the copy of the file that the coworker is using has been changed. This isn't about Git. He, or you, or someone must be doing something that changes that copy of the file. I don't know enough about your environment to guess how that's happening. In particular, I don't know what "the server" is.